# Check if url has domain name and not an ip

Tags: javascript

How can I check if an url is made with an ip address instead of a domain name?

For example:

```
http://www.yeouuuuu.com/bla
https://www.bbc.co.uk/something
http://yeou:password@my.service.com/
//return true;
http://172.10.10.100/test
//return false; because there is an IP.
```

ip4 regex:

```
ipv4 = RegExp('((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|
  [0-9])\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])');
```

Comment: Show us how you are testing your regex against your inputs and what does not work.

Comment: I don't aggree with this duplicate. I read that post before writing this. I want to know if my variable url consists of an dns name and not an ip address.

Comment: @yeouuu: The duplicate contains two regular expressions, one for a hostname and one for an IP address. It should be fairly easy for you to use these to get your answer.

Comment: @FelixKling I think writing a regex to test all the above cases (example: http://yeou:password@my.service.com/) is a bit more complex than just knowing if it contains an ip or a domainname. And more people might benefit from the answer.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that the other one doesn't cover user credentials. So you actually want to check more than just the domain name. You should probably point that out more explicitly in your question.

Comment: OTOH, there are [*so many* URL regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+valid+url) on Stack Overflow, that I don't see the value of adding yet another. It shouldn't be difficult to take any of these and adjust them to your needs.

Comment: Well I found the answer and posted it here. I can't imagine a lot of people enjoy writing silly regexes, so it's helpfull imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex let's you test if your url consists of ipv4 urls

```
let ipv4Url = RegExp([
    '^https?:\/\/([a-z0-9\\.\\-_%]+:([a-z0-9\\.\\-_%])+?@)?',
    '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4',
    '][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])?',
    '(:[0-9]+)?(\/[^\\s]*)?$'
].join(''), 'i');

ipv4Url.test('http://yeou:test@10.10.10.10/hello');
//returns true
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not just test of `window.location.hostname` has any letter?

```
window.location.hostname.match(/[a-z]/i)
```

If it has even one letter then it's not an IP address. No?

Comment: Yes, but only because it does not have an `a-z` letter doesn't make it an ip address.

Comment: Touche. Didn't think about that.

Comment: In my case, I also needed to consider IPv6. I've written an updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Using your regex:

```
function isIP( address ){ 
    r = RegExp('^http[s]?:\/\/((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])');
    return r.test( address )
}
```

Returns true if the address isn't a domain name. If the URL contains an IP address after the domain, it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

You probably also want to consider IPv6. IPv6 is [always](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#host-writing) surrounded by square brackets. So the final code might look like

```js
function isCurrentHostIp() {
   const containsLetter = /[a-zA-z]/.test(location.hostname)

   const isIPv6 = 
       location.hostname.startsWith('[') && 
       location.hostname.endsWith(']')

  return !containsLetter || isIPv6
}
```

## Nitpicking

Actually, even IPv4 addresses in `window.location.hostname` can contain letters. Try to open `http://192.168.0x1.0x1` or `http://0xc0.0xa8.1.1` (my browser opens http://192.168.1.1 for both)

The WHATWG spec for URL [describes](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#ipv4-number-parser) that browser should try to parse components of IPv4 in base 16 and base 8

Depending on your use case, considering such IPs might be overkill

Answer (score -1):

You can run your RegExp against `window.location.hostname`